# How to create a databse table with Cloudant?

Tags: cloudant, nosql

I'm new to Cloudant nosql database and i'm used to use mysql before.

- What i'm trying to do is to create a database called "**users**" and create a

table with the with the following structure:

```
username
firstname
lastname
email
age
```

with mysql i would have do the following to create a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE users
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and to create the table with mysql i would do the following

```
CREATE TABLE Myusers (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
age INT
)
```

Could someone guide me step by step how to do the same with Cloudant? and explain things please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant is a JSON document store, so you don't create tables or rows, you create documents which contain the information for a single record.

**How to create a database.**

You create a database in cloudant using the rest API.  To create a database you make a PUT request to

```
https://username.cloudant.com/$db
```

Where $db is the database name.

Running the following curl command will create the database users in your cloudant account (replace username and password as appropriate).

```
curl -X PUT https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/users
```

**Saving data to the database**

To add information to your database you create a JSON object that contains all the information you wish to store in a single record for example :

```
{"username":"username", "firstname":"name", "second name":"name","email":"email","age":25"}
```

You add this information to the database by putting the data to

```
https://username.cloudant.com/users/$docid
```

Where $docid is an id for the document. Note that the ID is optional, you can also post directly to the database and it I'll generate the doc Id for you.

Let's put these bits together to add the document to the db

```
curl https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/username -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' {"username":"username", "firstname":"name", "second name":"name","email":"email","age":25"}'
```

**Reading data**

To read the data we have just written (remember due to eventual consistency we may not get any data back)

```
curl https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/username
```

Which will return

```
  {"_id":"username","_revid":1-rheijdhryahsbrnwjsh","username":"username", "firstname":"name", "second name":"name,"email":"email","age":25"}
```

Note that that the database has added the doc Id and the revision id to the json that is returned using _ prefixed fields.